# SparkException: Task not serializable - Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, junit5

I am migrating my tests from JUnit4 to JUnit5. Code is working fine in JUnit4, but in JUnit 5, it is throwing `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable`  exception. I tried multiple ways, but now working. `testAlternativeVegetableIdWithDifferentReadCount` test is failing, when in `assertTrue` line. And when I tried to show Dataset value, it is also throwing an error. What I am doing wrong?

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ExportLogicTest implements Serializable {

    @Mock(serializable = true)
    private TimeProvider timeProvider = new TimeProvider();

    @Mock(serializable = true)
    private VCFVariantDataProvider vcfVariantDataProvider;

    @Mock(serializable = true)
    private VCFGenotypeProvider vcfGenotypeProvider;

    @Mock(serializable = true)
    private AllelesToTargetAssemblyConverter targetToAssemblyConverter;

    private ExporterParameters<VariantGenotypeExportRequest> defaultParameters = new ExporterParameters<>();

    private static SparkSession sparkSession;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void beforeAll() {
        System.setProperty("parametersKeys", "unit-tests");
        sparkSession = SparkSessionTestWrapper.getSparkSession();
    }

    @AfterAll
    public static void afterAll() {
        sparkSession.close();
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void afterEach() {
        sparkSession.sql("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS dbname CASCADE");
    }

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        sparkSession = SparkSessionTestWrapper.getSparkSession();
        sparkSession.sql("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS dbname");
        VariantGenotypeExportRequest request = new VariantGenotypeExportRequest();
        List<MaterialsProjectIdPairs> projectIdPairsList = new LinkedList<>();
        MaterialsProjectIdPairs projectIdPairs1 = new MaterialsProjectIdPairs();
        projectIdPairs1.setProjectId("project1");
        projectIdPairsList.add(projectIdPairs1);
        request.setProjectAndMaterialsPairs(projectIdPairsList);
        defaultParameters.setExportRequest(request);
    }

    @Test
    void testAlternativeVegetableIdWithDifferentReadCount() throws IOException {
        TestFiles testFiles = new TestFiles("different_read_count_for_the_same_allele_uid");
        saveAsTable(readAssemblyCSV(testFiles.getAssemblyFile(), sparkSession), PropertyUtils.getAssemblyTable());
        defaultParameters.getExportRequest().setAssemblyId("15");

        VCFExportLogic exporter = createVCFExporterAndSetUpDefaultParameters(testFiles, sparkSession);

        Dataset<String> result = vcfFileAndHeaderToString(exporter.runExport(defaultParameters));
        Dataset<String> expectedDF = readExpectedFileToDS(testFiles.getExpectedResult(), sparkSession);
        result.show();
        assertTrue(JavaSparkHelper.equalsDataSets(result, expectedDF));
    }

    private Dataset<String> vcfFileAndHeaderToString(VCFHeaderAndRows headerAndRows) {
        List<String> columns = Collections.singletonList(headerAndRows.getHeader().get(headerAndRows.getHeader().size() - 1));
        Dataset<String> columnsDS = sparkSession.sqlContext().createDataset(columns, Encoders.STRING());
        Dataset<String> rows = headerAndRows.getRows()
                .map((MapFunction<VCFRow, String>) x -> x.getRow(), Encoders.STRING());
        return columnsDS.union(rows).coalesce(1);
    }

}
```

**Error looks like as below** I am using gradle project.

```
Task not serializable
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:403)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:393)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2326)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1.apply(RDD.scala:850)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1.apply(RDD.scala:849)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.mockito.internal.junit.DefaultStubbingLookupListener
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.mockito.internal.junit.DefaultStubbingLookupListener, value: org.mockito.internal.junit.DefaultStubbingLookupListener@534cc4a1)
    - writeObject data (class: java.util.ArrayList)
    - object (class java.util.ArrayList, [org.mockito.internal.junit.DefaultStubbingLookupListener@534cc4a1])
```

Comment: How did you use Mockito in JUnit 4? Jupiter‘s MockitoExtension configures a few defaults that might be in conflict with your old testing approach.

Comment: in JUnit 4, it was ```@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)``` in class definition. And I changed it to ```@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)``` in JUnit 5. What do you recommend to do?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved above issue by increasing jupiter-engine and mockito versions in build.gradle file.

```
junit-jupiter-engine:5.6.0 -> 5.8.2
mockito-junit-jupiter:2.23.4 -> 4.6.1
```

After that `Task not serializable` issue is lost. Even if I remove **implements Serializable** from Test class definition, it is working fine